# How to write sql for the below situation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, retain

I have situation like this:

For each week there is a combination of key, product and some value for it.

I want to retain the value in next week, if that particular combination of key and product does not occur.

I will be using **SQL server 2008**,

An example would be:

```
week1 > key1>Prod1>0.1

week2>key2>prod1>0.2
```

I want to retain key1>prod1 combination in next week 2, because it's not there.

Comment: What database do you use? Provide an input and the desired output, please

Comment: Could you give us the DDL?